# ln: failed to create symbolic link: Input/output error

Tags: bash, vagrant-windows

I am setting myself up on a new project that I didn't write. It uses vagrant for setup. The first time I ran vagrant up I ran into ntfs error and 2nd time line ending related issues, both of which are cleaned up (windows 10, project is linux). Now however I am getting Input/output error when creating a symbolic link. Error is below. I have tried both in phpstorm's terminal and cmd, both running administrator.

```
default: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/xxxxxx-api-v2/deploy/helper/update_composer.sh': Input/output error
```

In both terminals, prior to the error, I have these few lines

```
default:   - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.185.10): Extracting archive
default:   - Installing google/apiclient-services (v0.255.0): Extracting archive
default:  0/2 [>---------------------------]   0%    Install of aws/aws-sdk-php failed
default:     Install of google/apiclient-services failed
default:
default: In Filesystem.php line 330:
default:
default:   Could not delete /var/xxxxxx-api-v2/app/vendor/composer/5316bb55/aws-aws-sd
default:   k-php-667a83e/src/data:
default:
```

I am unsure if this is related. What line I think is running in the scripts that fails is either

```
sudo -u www-data ln -s /var/${PROJECT_NAME}/deploy/helper/update_composer_dev.sh /var/${PROJECT_NAME}/deploy/helper/update_composer.sh
```

or

```
sudo -u www-data ln -s /var/${PROJECT_NAME}/deploy/helper/update_composer_prod.sh /var/${PROJECT_NAME}/deploy/helper/update_composer.sh
```

and both those respective scripts (update_composer_dev/prod) look the same save for 2 flags. Details below

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ${0%/*}

PROJECT_NAME=$(cat ../../deploy/config/project_name)

cd ../../app
sudo -u www-data COMPOSER_HOME=/var/tmp/${PROJECT_NAME}/.composer HOME=/var/tmp/${PROJECT_NAME} php composer.phar self-update --2
sudo -u www-data COMPOSER_HOME=/var/tmp/${PROJECT_NAME}/.composer php composer.phar update
```

this is dev version, prod just removes the --2 flag and adds --no-dev to the last line.

I don't actually know how to figure what's wrong.

Any incorrect tags or missing info please inform me about and I will add/fix. Thanks in advance.